Getting line to polygons algorithm work in QGIS

I'm new to QGIS and trying to make a map of the Roman Empire. I first copy a select of the coast and then close it with a line. But even for islands that I don't touch, when I run the line to polygons, it causes issues. I've tried running check validity and don't see any issue. What is wrong?

The line to polygon tool can produce odd results.  The preferred tool for creating polygons from lines is the polygonize tool.  If that fails to produce a polygon it likely is because there is a gap, even a small one, between line endpoints.  You can run the snap geometries to layer tool or the GRASS v.clean tool with a snap tolerance sufficient to close the gap, then run polygonize.

Please indicate the exact QGIS version used and please provide the layer.
What do you mean exactly with "I first copy a select of the coast and then close it with a line"?
Is such line is a single LineString or is it a MultiLinesString containing multiple lines correctly connected and having the same versus? Please provide the sample layer.

Why do you create polygons yourself and don't use pre-existing date, e.g. from OpenStreetMap or https://gadm.org? Islands like Corsica exist there and their shape has not changed dramatically since roman  times. And to give a good answer to why your procedure fails, we need more information about what exactly you have, how you proceed in detail and where you're stuck. See [tour]
